# Error: failed to serialize user into session. Wrong function passed to serializeUser()?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to do my first steps with the Express framework for Node. I was trying to implement a tiny authentication example, using Passport. However, I can't make it work; I keep getting the error: `Error: failed to serialize user into session`.

I installed node-inspector to try to see what's going on. Apparently, my serialization function is being called, and it executes `done(null, 0)` as expected. I tried taking a look at Passport code, but I couldn't understand what the problem is. This is pretty much my first attempt at a Node application so I'm not familiar with the code. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks.

```
var express = require('express');
var jade = require('jade');

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();

/*
 * Settings
 */

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'cat in the bag' }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done) {
            done(null, { id: 0, username: 'juancito' });
        }
    ));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        done(null, 'juancito');
    });
});



/*
 * Routes
 */

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Welcome!' });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    if (req.user)
        return res.redirect('/');

    res.render('login', { title: 'Log in' });
});

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    })
);

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logOut();
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000.');
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is a common symptom, but this is a strange cause (id == 0). My ids (like most people's ids) are all non-0, and I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that `0` is a false-y value in JavaScript, so Passport thinks you haven't serialized your user.

```
done(null, 0)  // don't serialize users to a 0 number
```

I'd recommend starting user IDs at 1 (which happens in SQL databases), or (if you really need integers beginning at 0) serialize them as strings to the session.

```
done(null, 0.toString())
```

Comment: Thanks, Jared! You were right. So, 1, 2, 3 are valid serializations for objects, but 0 isn't because the language considers 0 a falsy value. Isn't that a bug in the lib?

Comment: Yeah, feel free to file an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should assign your serialize/deserialize callbacks before calling passport.initialize() and passport.session().

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        done(null, { id: 0, username: 'juancito' });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    done(null, 'juancito');
});

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'cat in the bag' }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

});
```

Comment: Spot on. I had the error appearing only after I tried to access a page with a session restored from the database. Since I had the serialize/ deserialize set only after the first login the server has processed.

Comment: This made no difference for me.

Comment: Just saw this, if it still doesn't work try doing ```done(null, toString(user.id))``` instead of  ```done(null, user.id)```